# What is the verb for trying to join a group of people when someone is unwanted in it?

Tags: word-choice

Let's say there is a guy who wants to be part of some group of people. And although is let to know that he is unwanted, he is annoyingly trying to join the people. What is the most common verb for it?

Comment: There are probably plenty of (more or less well-known) slang terms, but informal [**hanger-on**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hanger-on) *(an unwanted person who remains in a place or with a group, another person, etc., in the hope of personal gain)* might suit, depending on your exact context.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is the verb for it?

Comment: There isn't one. Or at least, I *doubt* there will be a simple "verb" for this activity, such as you might hope to find defined in a dictionary. Just use more words to convey the meaning you want.

Comment: Verbs might include *to intrude* or *to impose*. But the question remains too broad to give a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any *formal* word for such behavior, but informally the person will be be to said to "butt in" or "horn in".

(Typically, "butt in" means the person is participating without being wanted, and thereby obstructing the function of the group — a person who butts into a conversation by interrupting.  "Horning in" implies that the person is not just obstructing the group but actually misappropriating some of the benefits of the group — if you horn in on a picnic, you are eating some of the food.)

Comment: Could you tell me whag such a person is called?

Comment: The guy horning in on a picnic or party might be called an ***interloper*** or ***gatecrasher***, but I don't think either of those would normally be used to describe, say, someone who constantly tries to inveigle his way into a group of people who hang out together, but won't allow this other person to join their group even though he keeps hovering around them trying to be accepted.